# Inter- and intra-observer agreement based on regression coefficients

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, ordinal-data, agreement-statistics

I have a following study design for a group of people looking at a picture:

- Ordinal outcome variable - based on picture, how sure you are that A is true from 1 to 5
- Binary predictor - a golden standard for A (for each picture if A is true)
- Grouping factor
- And covariate - still in question, could be dropped.

As well as several "observers" each reviewing same set of pictures. (with repeat scoring after several weeks).

It seems that using a latent variable model would allow me to estimate grouping effect.

Question is: can I get some measure of agreement between observers? For example including observers as a random effect (possibly interaction and slope on golden standard) and estimating it's deviation?
Some other metrics?